# Writing to a csv file in Python, how to make this code more efficient?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have created a code that takes the user's input and creates 5 teams and writes them to the csv file, the code works but it is less efficient as every time the code runs the user will have to redo all the teams, instead of being able to change one team or add one team at one time, is there any possible solution to this? Thank you in advance.

```
import csv

def adding_teams():

    team_1 = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 1.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
        team_1.append(name)

    print("\n")

    team_2 = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 2.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
        team_2.append(name)

    print("\n")

    team_3 = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 3.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
        team_3.append(name)

    print("\n")

    team_4 = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 4.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
        team_4.append(name)

    print("\n")

    team_5 = []
    for i in range(0,6):
        name = str(input("You are now entering the data for Team 5.\nYou will see this 6 times, enter the team's name first then the members, all individually."))
        team_5.append(name)

    print("\n")


    header_teams = ['TeamName', 'Member1', 'Memberb2', 'Member3', 'Member4', 'Member5']
    teams_data = [
        team_1,
        team_2,
        team_3,
        team_4,
        team_5]


    with open('teams.csv', 'w', newline = '', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        #writing the header for the csv file.
        writer.writerow(header_teams)

    with open('teams.csv', 'a', newline = '', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        #writing the data for each team.
        writer.writerows(teams_data)

    f.close()

adding_teams()
```

Comment: Well you are writing it to a csv, why dont you read it back and update ?

Comment: You can extract the code in the loop to a different function which receives the team number as a parameter. Or just move the loop to a separate function and call it everytime.

Comment: Reading it back to memory, adding one row, and then updating the whole file would be quite inefficient. One lightning fast alternative would be to _append_ to the file, and write the extra lines on the end, without reading it first.

Comment: @anosha_rehan thank you I will try make a function for adding a team and call it to add the team to the csv file.